# Blur the edges of an image or background image with CSS

Tags: html, css, filter

I know there are a bunch of new CSS filters and I am wondering if there is a way to apply those to an image or background image.  Everything I have read talks about softening the image with a drop shadow, however, a drop shadow is a color, and I want to blur the edges of images so that I could blend them together more seamlessly if they were next to each other.  Right now it looks like you can only go with a drop shadow or apply a blur to the entire image (based on what I have read).

The closest I can come up with is a semi-transparent box shadow....like this

```
-webkit-box-shadow: 12px 29px 81px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
-moz-box-shadow: 12px 29px 81px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
box-shadow: 12px 29px 81px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
```

Comment: Give one link, which you want exactly.
and develop a fiddle with your image.We could help you to achieve your requirement.

Answer (score 129, accepted):

If what you're looking for is simply to blur the image edges you can simply use the box-shadow with an inset.

Working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/d9Q5H/1/

[image: Screenshot]

Code snippet:

```css
.image-blurred-edge {
  background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/200/300');
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  /* you need to match the shadow color to your background or image border for the desired effect*/
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px 8px white inset;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-blurred-edge"></div>
```

Comment: this works, and if you want a dynamic width/height you can add also the image inside the div with style="visibility;hidden;"

Comment: With CSS it's possible to create a circle. Just use "border-radius:50%".  The above method for creating an image soft edge does not appear to work with 'circle' images.

Comment: Thanks @Robin Manoli my headache is finally over - wish I could upvote your comment more

Comment: The Codepen doesn't seem to be working, at least on Chrome.

Answer (score 21):

I'm not entirely sure what visual end result you're after, but here's an easy way to blur an image's edge: place a div with the image inside another div with the blurred image.

**Working example here:**
http://jsfiddle.net/ZY5hn/1/

[image: Screenshot]

Code snippet:

```css
.placeholder {
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  /* this is the only relevant part for the example */
}


/* both DIVs have the same image */

.bg-image-blur,
.bg-image {
  background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/200/300');
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}


/* blur the background, to make blurred edges that overflow the unblurred image that is on top */

.bg-image-blur {
  -webkit-filter: blur(20px);
  -moz-filter: blur(20px);
  -o-filter: blur(20px);
  -ms-filter: blur(20px);
  filter: blur(20px);
}


/* I added this DIV in case you need to place content inside */

.content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 0 3px #000;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
HTML:

<div class="placeholder">
  <!-- blurred background image for blurred edge -->
  <div class="bg-image-blur"></div>
  <!-- same image, no blur -->
  <div class="bg-image"></div>
  <!-- content -->
  <div class="content">Blurred Image Edges</div>
</div>
```

Notice the blurred effect is using the image, so it changes with the image color.

I hope this helps.

Comment: This is great. I was really after a solution to remove the "hard" edges of the image (so that I could butt two images against each other and have a smooth transition) but I think this is a good start.

Comment: Oh, then that's easier. I've added another answer on how to achieve that effect. If you need to place two images and transition between them, simply choose the transition color and use the box-shadow like I explained in my second answer.

Answer (score 6):

If you set the image in div, you also must set both height and width. This may cause the image to lose its proportion. In addition, you must set the image URL in CSS instead of HTML.

Instead, you can set the image using the IMG tag. In the container class you can only set the width in percent or pixel and the height will automatically maintain proportion.

This is also more effective for accessibility of search engines and reading engines to define an image using an IMG tag.

```css
.container {
    margin: auto;
    width: 200px;
    position: relative;
}

img {
    width: 100%;
}

.block {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    box-shadow: inset -10px -10px 10px 20px white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200">
    <!-- http://lorempixel.com/200/200/city -->
    <div class="block"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>test</title>

<style>
#grad1 {
  height: 400px;
  width: 600px;
  background-image: url(t1.jpg);/* Select Image Hare */
}


#gradup {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: radial-gradient(transparent 20%, white 70%); /* Set radial-gradient to faded edges */

}
</style>

</head>

<body>
<h1>Fade Image Edge With Radial Gradient</h1>

<div id="grad1"><div id="gradup"></div></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

[This is the best tutorial I found on blurring edges of actual `img` html element](https://codepen.io/burtclan/pen/PoOOey).

Create element overlapping the one you want the blur edge effect on and add box shadow on that element. You can use `:after` on the on the `img` parent element.

Comment: `:before` and `:after` do not work on `<img>'.

Comment: Also, tutorial is not a tutorial at all, but a codepen, and it does not fade the edges of the "actual `img` html element" but use a wrapper element and fades that.