# How to use image as its own background-image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress

I wanted to create the new iOS music app effect in my website, and use an image it as its own `background-image` attribute in css, and also apply a blur on it. I tried manually, but using `filter:blur()` in my image also blurs the hole div.

I have a structure like this:

```
<div class="post-cover">
<img src="#"/>
</div>
```

Unfortunately I don't know how automate thought javascript, jQuery or PHP. I'm using WordPress and the final effect I'd like to have is:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is to transform the img tag into de div tag brackground, then

```
$(".post-cover").each(function(){
  var img = $(this).find("img");
  $(this).css({
    "background-image": "url('"+img.prop("src")+"')",
    //Any other CSS background propriety
    //If your div don't have a fixed width and height
    width: img.width(),
    height: img.height()
  });
  img.remove();
});
```

For the blur effect in your CSS user the next styles:

```
.post-cover{
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  -moz-filter: blur(5px);
  -o-filter: blur(5px);
  -ms-filter: blur(5px);
  filter: blur(5px);
}
```

EDIT
So then Same JS snippet but

```
<div style="position: relative;">
  <div class="blur-content">
  </div>
  <div class="post-cover">
    <img>
  </div>
</div>

.post-cover{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
.blur-content{
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  -moz-filter: blur(5px);
  -o-filter: blur(5px);
  -ms-filter: blur(5px);
  filter: blur(5px);
}
```

Comment: This approach is almost what I need. But actually I need the original image to be above the blurred, to get that effect..

Comment: Unfortunately I can't modify my html structure.. so the `blur-content` div can not be created.. It seems your old JS approach is good, it transformed the image in its background-image attribute. Isn't it possible to just copy the `scr=` attribute and set it as separate element (to be able to apply the filter)? Or to apply the filter in the post-cover div, and insert the image url as a pseudo after element? I don't know what would fit..

Comment: Yes, as long as you keep the blur content and the one with the background image separated, and don't forget to set the relative css property to the parent and the absolute property to the image div so you can overlap them, you can do all of this with jQuery.

Comment: I managed by your solution to make this: http://www.hitsebeats.com/2016/09/blink-182-steve-aoki-bored-to-death-steve-aoki-remix-single-itunes-plus, but even with the correct z-index, it is now showing before.. any idea?

Comment: Hi, look at this post, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24709915/blur-the-edges-of-an-image-or-background-image-with-css, it should help you. Look at the elements you need and the styles, then use a modification of my jQuery snippet.

Answer (score 0):

To blur only the image use this code:

```
 .post-cover img {
    filter:blur();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you are after.  Your demo image and the description of your result do not seem to align.  From your description, I think you want something like this.

```css
.post-cover {
  position: relative;
  height: 400px;
  width: 300px;
}

.post-cover #bg {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  filter: blur(8px);
  z-index: -1
}

.post-cover #orig {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="post-cover">
  <img id="bg" src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/300"/>
  <img id="orig" src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/300"/>
</div>
```