# How to blur image edges in foreground when using Bootstrap 4

Tags: css, image, bootstrap-4, blur

I'm trying to blur the edges of an image like the picture shown at https://stackoverflow.com/a/24953573.

I need to do this on a foreground image (not one set in css) because the img url is dynamically changed. But box-shadow seems to have no effect on a foreground image.  Also I'm using the Bootstrap 4.3 `img-fluid` class.

In other words, the code at the SO post referenced above works, but the edges on this image are not blurred (css inline for simplicity):

```
<img src="/images/mypic.jpg" 
    class="img-fluid" 
    style="box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px white inset;">
```

`.img-fluid` sets `max-width: 100%` and `height:auto`.  I tried over-riding these with specific values (which I don't want to do to maintain a responsive image), but it had no effect either.

Comment: *because the img url is dynamically changed* --> you can use inline style to add background image too

Comment: @TemaniAfif - true but height has to be specified as a fixed value; so doesn't work with img-fluid's `height: auto`

Comment: you add both of them, a div that wrap the image and the div will get the background and you make the image with opacity:0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap `img` tag by `div` element with class name of `.img-blur` so use the `:after` pseudo-element can be used to insert some content after the content of an element.

```css
.img-blur{
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.img-blur:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px 10px #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row" >
    <div class="col-4 my-3">
      <div class="img-blur">
        <img class="img-fluid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x400/22ff22">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 my-3">
      <div class="img-blur">
        <img class="img-fluid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x400/ffff22">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 my-3">
      <div class="img-blur">
        <img class="img-fluid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x400/22ff22">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect!  This is the simplest way achieve the goal without using javascript or workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunally, CSS 'Inset' Box shadows don't work on `img` tags. To workaround this, you have a few couple options, for example, is possible wrap the image on a `div` tag and use a pseudo-element to apply the `box-shadow` on it.

The problem here is that, as standard, the `div` tag is a "Block" element, and as so will cover the entire parent width. You could fix this applying a `display: inline-block` or a `float: left` property. Perhaps is not the best "standard-compliant", but will work on this case. I attach a example with this concept below:

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

div:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px white inset;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" class="img-fluid">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but the use of radial-gradient isn't what I'm after. I don't won't to blur the image, only the edges.  Can you show some code for your first "workaround"? I'm not clear on how to use pseudo-elements.

Comment: Got it, i updated the snippet above showing how to achieve the effect using CSS pseudo-elements and box-shadow. Additionaly i attach a link to CodePen with both cases: https://codepen.io/geekzolanos-dev/pen/ZEGBJMO

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with style images with `inset`.

But you have 2 alternatives to do this. You can add a container with position relative and inside put img with class `img-fluid` and div with positon absolute to this container.

The second option is to set a container with position relative and img inside and style that container with pseudo-class `::after`.

If you will do that it works but there will be a problem with the right box-shadow that if img is smaller than a container. You can fix these if you will use some JS code.

I made an example with jQuery ( cause you are using bootstrap and bootstrap is using jquery).

https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-wing-z9lhm