# I'm trying to use a gradient to produce a fade effect to the edges of my image. Why isn't it working?

Tags: css

I'd like to have the edges of my image be blurry or at least, fade out fuzzily. Nothing I have tried has worked, and I've looked at all the Stackoverflow questions. I'm using CSS, not Sass. Complicating matters is that I have a background image on the page that I'm overlaying with a white mask with .8 opacity. Is anyone able to help please?

Here is my [Codepen](https://codepen.io/lschneiderman/pen/GRYKLNr).

```css
.screen {
  position: relative;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: -6px;
}

.bg {
  background-image: url('//newsinteractive.post-gazette.com/.testLaura2/shutterstock_246230623.jpg');
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  filter: blur(3px);
}

.bg-mask {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .8);
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

#ballerina {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 1600px;
  height: 1000px;
  background-image: url('http://newsinteractive.post-gazette.com/.testLaura2/BalletAudition04xx_2992.jpg');
}

#ballerina:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 1600px;
  height: 1000px;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 100%);
  /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), color-stop(100%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)));
  /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 100%);
  /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 100%);
  /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 100%);
  /* IE10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 100%);
  /* W3C */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#00000000', endColorstr='#000000', GradientType=0);
  /* IE6-9 */
}
```

```html
<div class="bg"></div>
<div class="bg-mask"></div>

<div class="screen height-auto">
  <div id="ballerina"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you are trying to blur out your background image your filter is working?  if you are wanting it more opaque then you just need to increase the size of the radius you use.  Or am I not understanding what your issue is?

Comment: In `#ballerina` the url needs to read `https` instead of `http` and you need to add `#ballerina:after { content: ""; }`.

Comment: @Rene van der Lende: I made those changes, but it doesn't change the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up having to change my concept a bit. I got rid of the background image and mask for the whole page and just made the page background white with no mask. Then I used the solution from [Blur the edges of an image or background image with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24709915/blur-the-edges-of-an-image-or-background-image-with-css)

So my code looks like this:

html:

```
<div class="img-contain">
    <img src="http://newsinteractive.post-gazette.com/.testLaura2/BalletAudition04xx_2992.jpg">
    <div class="block"></div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.img-contain {
    margin: auto;
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
}

.img-contain img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.block {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    box-shadow: inset -0px -0px 20px 20px white;
}
```

Comment: I thought you mean for corners

Comment: But I'll add the code for 4 corners while editing my answer just in case you need it